# Recursive function generates duplicates in result

Tags: algorithm, recursion, coffeescript

I was playing around with some algorithms in coffescript and ended up wit some unexpected output. Here is my code:

```
traverse = (tree, stack) ->
  stack.push tree.node
  if not tree.branches
    stack
  else
    traverse branch, stack for branch in tree.branches

one  = { node: 1 }
two  = { node: 2 }
tree = { node: "+", branches: [one, two] }

console.log traverse  one, [] # => [ 1 ]
console.log traverse  two, [] # => [ 2 ]
console.log traverse tree, [] # => [ [ '+', 1, 2 ], [ '+', 1, 2 ] ]
```

The output I expect to get whilst traversing `tree` is `[ '+', 1, 2 ]` but this gets duplicated. Did I miss something simple here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If a function doesn't have an explicit `return` then the return value is the value of the last expression. The last expression in your function is this:

```
if not tree.branches
  stack
else
  traverse branch, stack for branch in tree.branches
```

Note that both `if`s and `for`s are expressions in CoffeeScript.

So what is the value of that `if` and hence the value of the function? If `tree.branches` is there then you get `stack`, otherwise you get the value of the `for`. A CoffeeScript `for` loop evaluates to an array:

```
a = (i for i in [0 .. 6])
# a is now [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

So if `tree.branches` is there, you end up returning an array of what `transverse` returns: an array of arrays of arrays of ... where the final arrays are all `stack`.

You just need to be a little more explicit about your return value, something like this should do the trick:

```
traverse = (tree, stack) ->
  stack.push tree.node
  if tree.branches
    traverse branch, stack for branch in tree.branches
  stack # <------------ Now we always return stack
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/2QJ9e/

Comment: Ah! You are indeed correct. The for loop returns an array (the outer []) and the stack is mutable. So even though the first time we return the stack the value is [+ 1], the second time its value gets mutated into [+ 1 2]. Thanks.